# print an int array in a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, int

I need to write a file(not binary) with students and each ones grades(int note[10] under this form). I do not get any errors but when I try to write the file just the last grade is printed, and I don't know how to print the entire list. For example (int nr_note means how many grades does the student have) if a students grades are 6, 8, 9 it just prints the 9.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    int nr_matricol;
    char nume[10];
    int nr_note;
    int note[10];
};

void citire_date(struct student *studenti, int n, FILE *f){
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Studentul %d\n", i+1);
        printf("Numarul matricol: "); scanf("%d", &(studenti+i)->nr_matricol);
        printf("Numele studentului: "); fflush(stdin); gets((studenti+i)->nume);
        printf("Numarul de note: "); scanf("%d", &(studenti+i)->nr_note);
        for(j=0;j<((studenti+i)->nr_note);j++){
            printf("Nota %d: ", j+1); scanf("%d", &(studenti+i)->note[i]);
        }
        fprintf(f, "Numar matricol: %d\nNume: %s\nNote: %d \n", ((studenti+i)->nr_matricol) ,((studenti+i)->nume), ((studenti+i)->note[i]));
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct student studenti[20];
    FILE *f;
    int n;

    f = fopen("studenti.txt", "w");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Nu s-a putut deschide/crea fisierul pentru scriere.");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Introduceti numarul de studenti: "); scanf("%d", &n);
    citire_date(studenti, n, f);
    fclose(f);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, `fflush()` should only be used in output streams, also you should use array syntax to handle `studenti`

Comment: If I don't use fflush() it reads "Numar matricol", and then jumps directly to "Numarul de note", it doeas not let me read "Nume"

Comment: The function: gets() has many problems, one major problem is it allows buffer overflow of the input buffer.  Suggest using: fgets()

Comment: @OlarAndrei use a function to clear the input buffer properly, using `fflush()` on input stream is **undefined behavior**, it won't do what you expect it to do most of the time.

Comment: when calling scanf() (and family) of functions, the returned value should always be checked to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.

Comment: Ok guys, thank you, I managed to write all the grades properly. I'll just document myself more about that fflush(). Thank you again.

Comment: scanf() does not (normally) consume a trailing newline.  the %s input/conversion operator will not skip over whitespace (like the newlline).  I would suggest using fgets() and then parsing the field with sscanf() however, a simple while( getchar() != '\n' );  loop will also consume the trailing whitespace (like the newline)

Comment: @OlarAndrei and get rid of the `gets()` function as pointed out by @user, even the linker is screaming at you to take it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change `citire_date()` function like this :

```
void citire_date(struct student *studenti, int n, FILE *f){
int i, j;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Studentul %d\n", i+1);
    printf("Numarul matricol: "); scanf("%d", &(studenti+i)->nr_matricol);
    printf("Numele studentului: "); fflush(stdin); gets((studenti+i)->nume);
    printf("Numarul de note: "); scanf("%d", &(studenti+i)->nr_note);
    for(j=0;j<((studenti+i)->nr_note);j++){
        printf("Nota %d: ", j+1); scanf("%d", &(studenti+i)->note[j]);
    }
    fprintf(f, "Numar matricol: %d\nNume: %s\n", ((studenti+i)->nr_matricol) ,((studenti+i)->nume) );
    // Printing the notes
    for(j=0;j<((studenti+i)->nr_note);j++){
        fprintf(f, "Note: %d = %d \n", j+1, ((studenti+i)->note[j]));
    }
}
```

}

You need to use a loop to print all the notes.